# AWS: CloudWatch logs service(cwlogs): database / disk full: database locked

Tags: sqlite, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am getting following errors in my logs. Though it's giving 2 errors , very likely it's not because of disk / database space issue and seems more of database locking problem. I researched and found that cwlogs write history records within sqlite db and hence that might be locking it out. Any inputs on this will be highly appreciated.

```
2017-06-02 23:01:27,331 - cwlogs.threads - ERROR - 3875 - Thread-3 - Exception caught in <EventBatchPublisher(Thread-3, started daemon 14047668)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cwlogs/threads.py", line 58, in run
    self._run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cwlogs/push.py", line 1391, in _run
    self._publish_event_batch()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cwlogs/push.py", line 1188, in _publish_event_batch
    self.publish_callback(self.event_batch, self.sequence_token)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cwlogs/push.py", line 795, in _record_state
    self.state_store.save(event_batch.source_id, state)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cwlogs/kvstore.py", line 47, in save
    key))
OperationalError: database or disk is full


2017-06-02 23:01:38,884 - cwlogs.threads - ERROR - 3875 - Thread-5 - Exception caught in <EventBatchPublisher(Thread-5, started daemon 14047666)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cwlogs/threads.py", line 58, in run
    self._run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cwlogs/push.py", line 1391, in _run
    self._publish_event_batch()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cwlogs/push.py", line 1188, in _publish_event_batch
    self.publish_callback(self.event_batch, self.sequence_token)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cwlogs/push.py", line 795, in _record_state
    self.state_store.save(event_batch.source_id, state)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cwlogs/kvstore.py", line 47, in save
    key))
OperationalError: database is locked
```

Comment: But it seems likely that the database is locked because the DB/disk is full.  It would make sense to lock a database that could no longer have data written to it.

Comment: ...Or the lock was created as part of a normal operation, but couldn't be removed, because of something being full.  I assume cwlogs/kvstore.py might tell you where the sqlite db is on the system.